# c# - How to have pointer to a tuple?

Tags: c#, pointers, tuples

Assume i have defined a tuple as shown below.

```
public Tuple<string, string> CValues = new Tuple<string, string>("abc", "def");
```

How do I define another variable that acts as a pointer to the above tuple? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does `CValuesReference` isn't a "reference"? You mean you want something like that: `var whatever = CValuesReference` ?

Comment: Yes you are right @Maciej

Comment: I'm trying to have a pointer using which I can access or change values of the above tuple. I know tuples are immutable. But their values can be changed with the `new` statement right.

Comment: You can pass your tuple by `ref` to a method and then assign a new object to it

Comment: Do you want a reference to the *tuple* -- which is immutable -- or to the *variable* -- which is mutable?  Do not confuse them; those are different things.  You can't change the color of your socks, but you can put different socks in the drawer. Do you want a reference to the socks or the drawer?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'variable' here. @Eric I thought the tuple named 'CValues' is immutable.

Comment: @Rama the class `Tuple` is immutable - its properties cannot be changed. The variable `CValues` is mutable - it can be assigned to something else. So you can point it to thick yellow socks or lightweight red socks (you can change what it points to) but you cannot change the thick socks to be green.

Comment: @Rama: There is no tuple named CValues. Tuples are not things that have names. There is a *variable* named CValues, and that variable *contains a reference to a tuple*. You can change the value of CValues; it's a *variable*, it may *vary*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net `Tuple` is an immutable reference class - it basically already is equivalent to a pointer, and there's no way to change the values, you can only create a new one.

You can use the `ref` keyword to make sure that the new instance is assigned...

```
var CValues = new Tuple<string, string>("abc", "def");

void ChangeCValues(ref Tuple<string, string> input) 
{
     values = new Tuple<string, string>(input.Item1 + "_x", input.Item2 + "_y")
}
```

After this `CValues` holds `"abc_x"` and `"def_y"`, but it's actually a new instance - the `ref` keyword ensures that the outer reference is updated.

If you assign another variable to `CValues` it will point to the same instance, but reassignment will point it to another...

```
var altValues = CValues;
// altValues.Item1 will be "abc"

ChangeCValues(ref altValues);
// altValues.Item1 will be "abc_x", but CValues.Item1 will be "abc"
```

What are you trying to do?

If you really want a mutable instance then you can create your own class:

```
class MyMutableTuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Item1 {get; set;}
    public T2 Item2 {get; set;}
}

var CValues = new MyMutableTuple<string, string>("abc", "def");

CValues.Item1 = "ghi"; // Works!
```

Comment: This answer cleared a lot of misconceptions for me. My only doubt now is can I change the values contained in `CValues` using `altValues` without the ref.

Comment: @Rama you can't change the values contained in `CValues` - you can create a new `Tuple` and assign it, but you can't change the values.

Comment: Yeah I get that. But creating a new tuple and assigning it to `altValues` will not change `CValues` right?  That's my problem

Comment: @Rama that's right. You can assign a new instance to `CValues` using the `ref` keyword, but that's it. What are you trying to do? `Tuple` is a lightweight immutable return class - typically you wouldn't use it as a public property anyway. Why not write your own class that is mutable in the ways that you want?

Comment: Since I'm working on a previously written code I cannot define my own class. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions. I found a workaround by which I was able to assign a new tuple to `CValues` itself @Keith

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is a class not struct. Therefore, your variable is a pointer.

Comment: My question is, what if want another pointer to this with a different name? Will `public Tuple<string, string> ptr = CValues; ` work?

Comment: In a language such as C# which has both [*references*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and [*pointers*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx), using the *wrong* name for one of these should always be avoided. The variable is a *reference*.

Comment: @Rama: I know an excellent way to find out: try it. Why are you asking us what that program fragment does? Write the code and run it and then you'll know what it does.